# Handle spark reading database mysql table throwing exception

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, amazon-aurora

I have a spark job that reads from AWS Aurora Mysql database. Unfortunately, the job keeps failing throwing an exception because of an invalid datetime in one of the records.

Sample code:

```
val jdbcUrl =
      s"jdbc:mysql://$dbHostname:$dbPort/$dbName?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&serverTimezone=UTC"

    val props = reportConf.connectionProps(db)

    val df = spark.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", jdbcUrl)
      .option("dbtable",
              s"(SELECT *, MOD($partitionColumn,10) AS partition_key FROM $table ORDER BY $partitionColumn) as $table") // DESC LIMIT 50000
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", password)
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
      .option("partitionColumn", "partition_key")
      .option("lowerBound", 0)
      .option("upperBound", 9)
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .load()
      .drop('partition_key)
```

I already tried converting the zeros date values to Null - `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` in my `jdbcUrl` but not working.

Preferably, I would like to skip the records or replace with some default values to filter later on instead of manually identifying the bad records in the database tables.

Any idea how to fix this in spark please ?

Exception:

```
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:678)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DAY_OF_MONTH
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
    at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.io.JdbcDateValueFactory.createFromDate(JdbcDateValueFactory.java:67)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.io.JdbcDateValueFactory.createFromDate(JdbcDateValueFactory.java:39)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.ZeroDateTimeToNullValueFactory.createFromDate(ZeroDateTimeToNullValueFactory.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:46)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:46)
    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:66)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:225)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.TextBufferRow.getValue(TextBufferRow.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNonStringValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:630)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDateOrTimestampValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:643)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:788)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:338)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNex
```

Comment: The date value maybe in wrong format or just plain wrong. Try converting it as string and read it.

Comment: I know is something wrong with the date value but how do you read it as string while using `spark.read.format('jdbc')` ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - `"mysql"                    % "mysql-connector-java"   % "
8.0.15",`

Comment: I'd suggest trying with 8.0.17, and otherwise you will really need to provide a [mre]. Either this is a bug (unlikely), or the value you are trying to read as a `java.sql.Date` is not in an appropriate format to be read as a date.